# Button Click Event on IronPython + Wpf

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio, ironpython

Im new to python and VS and im trying to make a simple GUI with a button.
Once I click the button I want it to print(5).

The code looks as following but when I click "run" it exits without any action:

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')

    BUTTON.Click += self.Button_Click
    print(5)

def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

XAML:

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="WpfApplication1" Height="300" Width="300"> 
       <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="BUTTON" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="101,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" Background="#FFFF1616"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Would be easier to discuss this if you could edit your answer to include the relevant portion of the xaml code?

Comment: added the XAML.

Comment: Also, If I may suggest a title edit, something like this would be more appropriate since your question is about ironpython/wpf and not Visual Studio:  `Button Click Event on IronPython + Wpf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an event handler for the button click. Just add this to your window init. (BUTTON should match the button's name on your xaml code)

```
ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
ui.BUTTON.Click += self.Button_Click
```

You can also achieve the same through the xaml code :

```
 <Button x:Name="BUTTON" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

Working code with comments below:

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'form.xaml')
        # not needed because event handler
        # is in XAML
        # to handle event on code, remove this from xaml's button tag:
        # Click="Button_Click"
        # and uncomment line below:
        # self.ui.Button.Click += self.Button_Click

    def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
        print('Button has clicked')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
    # Alternatively, below also works:
    # form = MyWindow()
    # form.ShowDialog()
```

See screenshot of working form:
[image]

Comment: I changed it but it didnt work, I updated the question mate.

Comment: it seems like after 1 compile the program stops compiling no matter what the code is inside and I get the following error: The program '[3484] ipyw.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please tell me what IDE you use? Because in Visual studio I cant see any output from this code (at least I dont get any error tho)

Comment: Happy to help. Not really using an IDE. It's just sublime editor, and I execute the code on a command prompt/terminal using `ipy.exe filename.py` (ipy.exe has to be added to system PATH)